# How to calculate ATR for previous candle?

Tags: pine-script, candlestick-chart

I just want to calculate ATR of 24 candles for previous candle. I already can do it for current candle

Here is what I've done so far but no results :

```
var atrSum = 0.0

if bar_index == 0
    for i = 1 to length1 + 1
        atrSum := (atrSum + max((high[i] - low[i]), abs(high[i] - close[i - 1]), (low - close[i -1])))

prevCandleAtr = atrSum / length1
```

Comment: What is wrong with the standard function `atr` and the ability to use `atr(24)[1]`?

Comment: I can't believe that it was that easy to reach, thank you so much